# Ros1: Callback function of subscriber only works after publishing 3-4 times

Tags: python, ros, ubuntu-20.04

Here's the part of the publisher code

```
def publish_data(topic, message):
    pub = rospy.Publisher(topic, UInt16, queue_size=100)
    rospy.init_node('Talker', anonymous=True)
    pub.publish(message)
    rospy.loginfo("MSG PUB LUL")
    rate = rospy.Rate(20) # publish at 10 Hz
    rate.sleep()`
```

and this is the whole subscriber code:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String
from std_msgs.msg import UInt16


def callback(servo_num, data):
    print("Callback function called with servo_num:", servo_num, "and data:", data.data)
    rospy.loginfo("Servo{}".format(servo_num))
    rospy.loginfo(data.data)

def listener():

    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("Servo1", UInt16, lambda data: callback(1, data))
    rospy.Subscriber("Servo2", UInt16, lambda data: callback(2, data))
    rospy.Subscriber("Servo3", UInt16, lambda data: callback(3, data))
    rospy.Subscriber("Servo4", UInt16, lambda data: callback(4, data))
    rospy.Subscriber("Servo5", UInt16, lambda data: callback(5, data))
    rospy.Subscriber("Servo6", UInt16, lambda data: callback(6, data))

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

When trying to publish the messages the rospy.loginfo("MSG PUB LUL") is out in the terminal with no problem. The problem is on the other side, that only outputs the print("Callback function called with servo_num:", servo_num, "and data:", data.data) after 2-3 times of publishing on the same topic. if the callback get called once, it will get called again with no problem unless i restart my code. Something i observer is that the 2-3 time may happen to be 3-4 times if the rate became too high like 200 or so. But if i try to put rate = 1 it doesn't really change much, same 2-m times of publishing to void before actually appearing.

Anyone encountered the same problem? Could really use some help here. Thanks in advance!

The code runs through the publisher just fine.
Expected:
print("Callback function called with servo_num:", servo_num, "and data:", data.data)
rospy.loginfo("Servo{}".format(servo_num))
rospy.loginfo(data.data)
to get excuted and see data in the terminal.

Actual:

Only happens after 2 to 3 times after publishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your publisher code is wrong. You shouldn't be creating a publisher and re-initializing a node every time you want to publish something. Instead, look at the following example:

```
pub = rospy.Publisher('some_topic', UInt16, queue_size=100)

def publish_data(message):
    pub.publish(message)
    rospy.loginfo("MSG PUB LUL")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('Talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.rate(20)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        msg = UInt16()
        msg.data = 5
        publish_data(msg)
        rate.sleep()
```

Note that if you want to publish to multiple topics, you should create multiple publishers in the same way.

Comment: I tried what you said but the issue is still there. However, there is some improvement. Previously i had to publish to each topic 2-3 times to get it tot work. Now, it's only the first topic and the rest works fine after that.